# How can I dump the pdns-recursor cache on Debian?

Tags: debian, powerdns, debian-buster

According to `man rec_control(1)` I should be able to dump the pdns-recursor cache to file with `rec_control dump-cache /tmp/the-cache`.

If I do that (on Debian buster), it says "dumped xxx records", but when I go look there is no file /tmp/the-cache. If I try the same command again, it says "Error opening dump file for writing: File exists". But I still can't find the file.

```
# rec_control dump-cache /tmp/the-cache
dumped 324 records

# cat /tmp/the-cache
cat: /tmp/the-cache: No such file or directory

# rec_control dump-cache /tmp/the-cache
Error opening dump file for writing: File exists

# cat /tmp/the-cache
cat: /tmp/the-cache: No such file or directory

# systemctl restart pdns-recursor.service

# rec_control dump-cache /tmp/the-cache
dumped 532 records

# cat /tmp/the-cache
cat: /tmp/the-cache: No such file or directory
```

Does Debian run pdns-recursor in a chroot jail maybe? Is there a way to dump the cache to a file where I can find it?

Answer (score 0):

Reddit user [u/hahainternet](https://www.reddit.com/user/hahainternet/) [solved it for me](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian/comments/g2b2fe/unable_to_dump_pdnsrecursor_cache/) in [r/debian](https://www.reddit.com/r/debian).

Debian's systemd unit file for the pdns-recursor service sandboxes the process. Its /tmp directory is still reachable from the host system though:

- via /tmp/systemd-private-[...]-pdns-recursor.service-[...]/tmp
- or by entering the process' namespace using `nsenter -a -t <pid of pdns-recursor>`.

One of these then allows access to /tmp/the-cache. A bit unwieldy, but it works.